# parsing error - syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR

Tags: php

I have this line in PHP:

```
if (( array_key_exists( $from, $arrRates ) && array_key_exists( $to, $arrRates ) )){
        return $amount + ( $arrRates[$to] \ $arrRates[$from] );
}
```

When I run it, I get the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NS_SEPARATOR in
C:\xampp\htdocs\MediaAlbumWeb\Utils\Utils.php on line 218
```

What is the `T_NS_SEPARATOR` and why is it unexpected? How to handle this error?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `/` instead of `\`.

The T_NS_SEPARATOR (`\`) is mainly used for escaping, what you are looking for is the token for division which is `/`:

```php
if (( array_key_exists( $from, $arrRates ) && array_key_exists( $to, $arrRates ) )) {
    return $amount + ( $arrRates[$to] / $arrRates[$from] );
}
```

Comment: Elaborating further, the `NS` in `T_NS_SEPARATOR` stands for `NAMESPACE`. [Here's the link to PHP Token Parsers for OP](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php)